# Has anyone done a double-slit experiment with another single slit in front of it?

Tags: double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality

I find myself wondering if anyone has done the following experiment, and what the results indicated.

My idea is a double slit, with another single slit, followed by a screen.

```
    |
    V

_ _____ _

____ ____

_________
```

Comment: Nice anecdote: page 6ff. http://pup.princeton.edu/chapters/s7573.pdf

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What distances do you envisage between the first and second set of slits? This is not a hard problem to analyze - even if the experiment has not been done, writing down what happens is straightforward but does depend on the dimensions. Are you considering this to be Fraunhofer diffraction (screen very far away compared to slit size) or Fresnel? Not obvious from your drawing...

Comment: @pfnuesel: Zee really wrote that???? If I am not mistaken string theory was born out of an attempt to model the strong force. I believe they only began using it to model quantum gravity after it went absolutely nowhere to explain parts of the standard model.

Comment: @CuriousOne: I suspect pfnuesel means the following section: *The professor’s nightmare*. When I first read this (some years ago now) it was like a light bulb going on!

Comment: @JohnRennie: You are right, I never got there... there is a problem with path integrals as ontology, though, and I believe even Feynman has pointed this out: the quantum mechanical system behaves AS IF a classical particle would be summing over all possible paths with a complex oscillating kernel, but that doesn't mean that nature is actually doing it that way. It's really the other way round: the QM solution is strongly suppressed outside of the classical path, which has deceived us for centuries about the actual structure of the microscopic world and it keeps deceiving many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the intermediate screen has no slit in it, then it's just a screen and on it we would expect to see the usual diffraction pattern from a double slit.

Now let us cut a slit in the intermediate screen. Light will pass through this hole and on the final (third) screen it will produce [the diffraction pattern from a single slit](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/sinslit.html). The intensity of this pattern depends on where we cut the slit. If we cut it at a maximum in the two slit diffraction pattern then it will be bright. If we cut it where the two slit pattern has a minimum then it will be dark.

So the result is actually quite boring. The first screen with the two slits just acts as a light source for the second screen with the single slit. There is no special interaction between the two screens.